# IF statement doesn't work within while loop - not sure if the conditions are right?

Tags: php, sql, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to echo entries from a database that have a lend_status of 1 or 2 and have written my while loop to get the entries but I'm not sure if my IF statement is correct or if this is the best way to go about this. I'm very new to PHP and SQL so any help would be really appreciated!

I've tried using an echo to see where it breaks and it seems to be the IF statement. I know the connection to the database works as I can echo information from it and have tested that.

```
<?php

// WHILE LOOP TO LOOK THROUGH THE DIFFERENT ROWS
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM laptop_system");
// DOESN'T HAVE TO BE AN ARRAY BUT GOOD PRACTICE TO PUT THIS IN (BELOW)
$STH->execute(array());
// WHILE LOOP TO LOOK THROUGH THE DIFFERENT ROWS


while ($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    $lend_status = $row->lend_status;
    $lend_id = $row->lend_id;
    $requestee = $row->user_id;
    $first_name = $row->first_name;
    $last_name = $row->last_name;

    $active_status = array(1,2);

if($lend_status == $active_status) {

      echo 'hello';
?>

<div>
<?php echo $requestee_name . '\n'; ?>

<?php echo 'hi'; ?>

</div>
<?php }} ?>
```

Comment: You could do `if(in_array($lend_status,$active_status)) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing a string / integer - one of the fields of your database row - to an array:

```
$lend_status = $row->lend_status;
...
$active_status = array(1,2);

if($lend_status == $active_status) {
```

If you want to check if the status is one of the values in the array, you can use for example [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if (in_array($lend_status, $active_status)) {
```

Comment: Brilliant Thank you that's just what I needed!